# Optimal binary search tree for English alphabet

Tags: tree, binary-tree, alphabet

I'm trying to understand how to use an optimal binary search tree, but I'm a bit confused. Would this be an example of such a tree?

```
                    E
       A                      T
  S         N            I             O
M   U    C      L     D     R       H     S
        Z Q    X J   K V   B P     Y G   F W
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; what is the criterion for optimality here? If the path length of a letter in the tree should roughly correspond to the probability of the letter, then the tree looks fine by rough inspection. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, the probability of the letters.